# Two way binding settings problem

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am having a problem using two way binding with a listpicker. I am able to set the value using c# but not in the `SelectedItem=".."` in xaml. The binding is returning the correct value (and is a value in the listpicker) as i have texted it by assigning the text to a textblock.

When the page loads, the binding used on the listpicker causes a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

The code i am using to set it is:

```
    // Update a setting value. If the setting does not exist, add the setting.
    public bool AddOrUpdateValue(string key, Object value)
    {
        bool valueChanged = false;

        try
        {
            // If new value is different, set the new value
            if (settingsStorage[key] != value)
            {
                settingsStorage[key] = value;
                valueChanged = true;
            }
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException)
        {
            settingsStorage.Add(key, value);
            valueChanged = true;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            settingsStorage.Add(key, value);
            valueChanged = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception occured whilst using IsolatedStorageSettings: " + e.ToString());
        }

        return valueChanged;
    }


    // Get the current value of the setting, if not found, set the setting to default value.
    public valueType GetValueOrDefault<valueType>(string key, valueType defaultValue)
    {
        valueType value;

        try
        {
            value = (valueType)settingsStorage[key];
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException)
        {
            value = defaultValue;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            value = defaultValue;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public string WeekBeginsSetting
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValueOrDefault<string>(WeekBeginsSettingKeyName, WeekBeginsSettingDefault);
        }
        set
        {
            AddOrUpdateValue(WeekBeginsSettingKeyName, value);
            Save();
        }
    }
```

And in the xaml:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="WeekStartDay" 
                    Header="Week begins on" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppSettings},
                                           Path=WeekBeginsSetting, 
                                           Mode=TwoWay}">
    <sys:String>monday</sys:String>
    <sys:String>sunday</sys:String>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

The `StaticResource AppSettings` is a resource from a seperate .cs file.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <local:ApplicationSettings x:Key="AppSettings"></local:ApplicationSettings>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean when you write `{StaticResource AppSettings}`? Is it a name of `resource` defined somewhere in `XAML` or a `static class`?

Comment: Yes sorry i forgot to mention AppSettings is a seperate class file

Comment: Is it a static class? Are you confusing `{x:Static AppSettings.WeekBeginsSetting}` with your current binding? Because Silverlight does not support `{x:Static}`.

Comment: same exact problem for me, both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex`. In particular Jame's comment below *I can get SelectedIndex to work but it just highlights the item and does not show it when the list picker is inactive - shows the first value in the list picker instead.* Opening a bounty to see if someone knows how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used Reflector to find the source of this exception. In ListPicker.cs the following method is overridden.

```
protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
```

In this method the following line will cause the exception if SelectedItem is set and SelectedIndex is -1 (which it is unless it's set before it's loaded). If SelectedItem isn't set this line is never reached (hence no exception).

```
else if (!object.Equals(base.get_Items().get_Item(this.SelectedIndex), this.SelectedItem))
```

To work around this (until they get this fixed) I have some suggestions.

**Workaround 1**

If you know the starting index which will be produced by the TwoWay binding then you can set the SelectedIndex property as well and the TwoWay Binding will work

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="WeekStartDay"
                    Header="Week begins on"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppSettings},
                                           Path=WeekBeginsSetting,
                                           Mode=TwoWay}"
                    SelectedIndex="1">
    <sys:String>monday</sys:String>
    <sys:String>sunday</sys:String>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

**Workaround 2**

Use the Loaded event and set the Binding from there instead

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="WeekStartDay"
                    Header="Week begins on"
                    Loaded="WeekStartDay_Loaded">
    <sys:String>monday</sys:String>
    <sys:String>sunday</sys:String>
</toolkit:ListPicker>

private void WeekStartDay_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Binding binding = new Binding();
    binding.Source = this.Resources["AppSettings"] as ApplicationSettings;
    binding.Path = new PropertyPath("WeekBeginsSetting");
    binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    WeekStartDay.SetBinding(ListPicker.SelectedItemProperty, binding);
}
```

Comment: thx for the detailed look at this. i think i'll go with workaround #2.

Answer (score 0):

Are you Firing the relevant property changed events?

Make sure that SelectedItem can have a two way binding.If not then try defining an ItemContainerStyle and bind the IsSelected property to a corresponding property on your object.Getting the selected item then becomes trivial.

Comment: Oops, i forgot to mention the problem i am having is when setting the listpicker it throws a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Answer (score 0):

If AppSettings is a collection then this is not going to work. You need to bind `SelectedItem` to a scalar value and unfortunately the "Silverlight 3.7" on WP7 doesn't support indexers in bindings.

Also, please don't use exceptions as flow control in your program, instead do something like this:

```
    try
    {
        // If new value is different, set the new value
        if(!settingsStorage.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            settingsStorage.Add(key, value);
            valueChanged = true;
        }
        else if(settingsStorage[key] != value)
        {
            settingsStorage[key] = value;
            valueChanged = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception occured whilst using IsolatedStorageSettings: " + e.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I can get SelectedIndex to work but it just highlights the item and does not show it when the list picker is inactive - shows the first value in the list picker instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using binding I simply set the selecteditem when the page loaded and used a selectionchanged event handler to update the value without confirmation (having a save button).